# Angular response appends object at the end

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my POST request:

```
$scope.TestPost = function (par1, par2) {

                $http.post('EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees',
                    {                    
                        par1: par1,
                        par2: par2       
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.employees = response.data;
                })
            };
```

And this is code that gets called on the server side. Code is called correctly and json serialized object is written to response:

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetAllEmployees(string par1, string par2)
{
    List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        List<Employee> _list = new List<Employee>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployees", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]),
                name = rdr["Name"].ToString(),
                gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString(),
                salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Salary"])
            };
            listEmployees.Add(emp);
        }
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();            
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listEmployees));
}
```

Response object is this - some strange line is appended at the end {"d":null} which I can not understand why. I am also receiving error on the client side: SyntaxError: Unexpected token:

```
"[{"id":1,"name":"Ben","gender":"Male","salary":55000},
{"id":2,"name":"Sara","gender":"Female","salary":68000},
{"id":3,"name":"Mark","gender":"Male","salary":57000},
{"id":4,"name":"Pam","gender":"Female","salary":53000},
{"id":5,"name":"Todd","gender":"Male","salary":60000}]{"d":null}"
```

Comment: is this question incomplete ? can you please include the outputs from server-side and client-side console.logs ? Thanks !

Comment: I am having problems comitting non-code. For JSON at the end SO is giving me error about code not correctly posted.

Comment: thanks for posting the logs. One more favor. I need the log for this variable: listEmployees. I think this error might be an outcome of your SQL query.

Comment: I don't think it is from SQL query because listEmployees is correctly serialized within `[ ... ]`. Is there any proxy server between your web browser and the java backend? What happens, if you e.g. try to return a simple primitive?

Comment: @badera do you think its the write method on the server side then ?

Comment: Yes, serialization is OK. I just can't understand why it looks so strange on the client side.

Comment: @FrenkyB Can you firebug it and see if the response itself has this or is Angular the culprit ? Its unlikely that its the latter ...

Comment: @82Tuskers - I was running developer tools inside Chrome. Watching at the json object it looks like I've posted above. (function is from angular.js). Here's the function: function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}

Comment: @FrenkyB you could use the network request and response for the call that you are making (under the network tab). You'd have everything there. Headers, cookies being sent and most importantly your response text .. that is key here .

Comment: @badera - yes, I've had Fiddler in between. I've shot down Fiddler, cleared cache, but it is still the same.

Comment: @FrenkyB: Can you post here the raw response data you can copy & paste from your network tab from the browser developer tools?

Comment: @badera - I've just tried several requests directly from Fiddler - they are all with this object at the end. That means, something gets wrong between server and client. I've also checked again raw response in Fiddler if I make a call directly from application and it is also with this object at the end.

Comment: I strongly suspect this section: Context.Response.Write. Serialization looks good. If you could post your network tab here, as @badera mentioned, it would do some help ..

Comment: Here is the response from network tab: [{"id":1,"name":"Ben","gender":"Male","salary":55000},{"id":2,"name":"Sara","gender":"Female","salary":68000},{"id":3,"name":"Mark","gender":"Male","salary":57000},{"id":4,"name":"Pam","gender":"Female","salary":53000},{"id":5,"name":"Todd","gender":"Male","salary":60000}]{"d":null}

Comment: Its server side then. Angular is not to blame :). You might want to check: Context.Response.Write

Comment: If that is difficult then you could log js.Serialize(listEmployees) and listEmployees. That will help you zero-in on the culprit.

Comment: @82Tuskers - this is the result from js.Serialize(listEmployees) - everything is OK. [{"id":1,"name":"Ben","gender":"Male","salary":55000},{"id":2,"name":"Sara","gender":"Female","salary":68000},{"id":3,"name":"Mark","gender":"Male","salary":57000},{"id":4,"name":"Pam","gender":"Female","salary":53000},{"id":5,"name":"Todd","gender":"Male","salary":60000}]

Comment: @82Tuskers - I've added this code at the end on the server side and now it's all OK: Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listEmployees));
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.End();

Comment: you could post the answer yourself now ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @82Tuskers and this post:
[Differences between Response.End() and Response.Flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925331/differences-between-response-end-and-response-flush)

I've found the solution. I've changed code at the end of server side function to:

```
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listEmployees));
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.End();
```

Response is now OK.