# download .zip files in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, download, zip

I'm trying to download .zip files from my .net C# application.  Not having success.  My code is below.  The file path and name is completely valid, just nothing seems to download.  Note how i have both "application/x-zip-compressed" and "application/zip" as content type (one commented out, tried both).  Neither works.  No indication of any error, just nothing downloading.

What's nutty is I swear this code was working just a couple of weeks ago, with the message popping up, "save as" option being given, just not happening now for whatever reason.

Anyone seeing anything wrong, or does my problem lie elsewhere outside the code??

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);

Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +   file.Name);

Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

//Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
```

Comment: So... what is the problem? What are you seeing? Any errors? Is it hanging?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting a `FileNotFoundException` at `Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());`.

To fix this, you have to use `Server.MapPath(...)` that adds the root directory of your application to the `filename`.
Furthermore you should `Flush()` and `End()` your `Response` properly to [force the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925331/differences-between-response-end-and-response-flush) to receive it.

```
string filename = "myfile.zip";
string serverpath = Server.MapPath($"~/{filename}");
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(serverpath);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```