# ASP.NET MVC: Not able to print data from DataTable to the HTML Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a database consisting a table, whose information I want to print on the browser. So what I did was:

```
In _Layout.cshtml:
       <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href=@Url.Action("ViewPage1","Billing")>Records</a>
       </li>
```

The page ViewPage1.cshtml contains:

```
<body>
<div>
    <a href=@Url.Action("Record_Page_Load", "Billing")>Print Records</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Which then calls the controller functions:

```
public DataTable GetRecords()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Article"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void Record_Page_Load()
    {

        DataTable dt = this.GetRecords();

        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        //html.Append("<html><body>");


        html.Append("<table border = '1'>");
        html.Append("<tr>");

        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }

        html.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
                Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(row[column.ColumnName]));
            }

            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        html.Append("/table");

        //html.Append("</body></html>");
    }

    public ActionResult ViewPage1()
    {
        return View("ViewPage1");
    }
```

Nothing is getting printed after on clicking Print Records.

To ensure that the DataTable is indeed getting filled, I tried printing the records in the output window of Visual Studio. The data was printing. So, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes as I see.

1. In your method `Record_Page_Load()` the second loop iteration you are starting with `</tr>` as seen below which should be an opening `<tr>`

   ```
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
       html.Append("</tr>");           // this one
       foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
       {
   ```
2. You are not outputting the content in Response stream at all and thus nothing shows in browser.

   ```
   html.Append("/table");
   Response.Write(html.ToString()); // Write the content to response stream
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! `Response.Write()` was required.

Answer (score 1):

You're building up the html table fine as i can tell but you are not outputting it. try flusing out using context to flush out to page using    `context.HttpContext.Response.Write(html);`

Comment: Can you explain where I need to put it and what must be the parameters?

Comment: Hi Since you are in a controller, you already have access to it, You can check it out with  this.HttpContext. To see an example of it in use, see this stack oveflow question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925331/differences-between-response-end-and-response-flush.